# Cannot cast to array (varchar) on Presto when unnesting a column

Tags: sql, presto, unnest

My data on the column `_idcounts` is like the following:

```
00A=10;500=20;500=3;00e=11;001(ta)=1;
```

As I want to unnest this column I did my query as:

```
SELECT t._idcounts, anotherField
 from myDataBase
CROSS JOIN UNNEST( cast(_idcounts as array<varchar>)) AS t (_idcounts);
```

But I have this as error:

> Failed to output to file. Query failed: Cannot cast varchar to array(varchar).

### Edit

If I remove the "`array`" from the "`cast`" command, so change to `CROSS JOIN UNNEST( cast(_idcounts as varchar))`, I have this error `Cannot unnest type: varchar`.

What can I try next?

Comment: `00A=10;500=20;500=3;00e=11;001(ta)=1;` does not look like a valid json array.

Comment: You are right.. I tried removing the json_parse and it dit not work neither. I forgot to remove this "json_parse" from the post

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just [`split`](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/string.html#split) on `;`:

```sql
--sample data
WITH dataset(id_str) AS (
  SELECT ('00A=10;500=20;500=3;00e=11;001(ta)=1;')
)

--query
SELECT t._idcounts
FROM dataset,
UNNEST(split(id_str,';')) AS t (_idcounts);
```

Output:

| _idcounts |
| --- |
| 00A=10 |
| 500=20 |
| 500=3 |
| 00e=11 |
| 001(ta)=1 |

Comment: Sorry to bother @Guru Stron, but as a streatch to this question, if I want to do a split again keeping the part before the "=" on a column and the part after the "=" on another column I should look for which command? I am searching on the documentation but I have not yet found. Thank you :)

Comment: @CatarinaNogueira use `split` again and then select first element of the result into first column and second - into second - `split(t._idcounts, '=')[1], split(t._idcounts, '=')[2]`